# artifactory query language for listing file types in date range

Tags: search, artifactory, specifications, aql, jfrog-mission-control

I am trying to list file types from a particular date range, so these large files can be deleted from artifactory storage, how to do this is confusing for me, so I thought of utilising the frog cli way using --spec switch, I have an expression but its not exactly working and I need to use the same for deletion also, any help would be highly appreciable.

```
curl -u admin: xxxxxxxxxx -i -X POST https://something.artifactory.com/artifactory/api/search/aql -d 'items.find({"type":"file","repo":"dev","created”:{“$before":“3w”},”$or":[{"name":{"$match":"*tar.gz"}, "name":{"$match":"*bz2"}, "name":{"$match":"*zip"}}]})'
```

Answer (score 2):

So I've tried doing the same as you and it seems to work. Several things you need to pay extra attention to will be formatting, for example, when I copy paste your example, there were quotation marks that were not the same. Second is that you use a JSON viewer tool that can assist with finding formatting issues. 
So this is what I did and it worked:

curl -u admin:password -i -X POST "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql" -T aql1.json

Where the aql1.json file looks like that:

```html
items.find({
  "type": "file",
  "repo": "libs-release-local",
  "created":{"$before": "1w"
},
"$or": [
  {
    "name": {
      "$match": "*.war"
    },
    "name": {
      "$match": "*.jar"
    }
  }
]
})
```

As you can see above I've added the aql section to a JSON file, this is not a must but makes life easier as I can see if I have any issues and also removes the possibility that my command will break due to a missing '\' (escaping) in front of special characters.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could not see your aql section in the recipe though, would you mind editing the script again, or may be i am lame to find it here, i tried expanding it but could not see it..

Comment: there you go:


items.find({


  "type": "file",


  "repo": "libs-release-local",


  "created":{"$before": "1w"},


"$or": [


  {


    "name": {


      "$match": "*.war"


    },


    "name": {


      "$match": "*.jar"


    }


  }


]
})